# Can I use ModelForm to filter a Date by range?

Tags: python, django

I want to filter some models in a list.

I know I can use `ModelForm` and filter in my view.

But my question is, how can I take advantage of ModelForms to filter a date field by range?

Also, I wish my form would generate two date widgets for my date field, one for start date and another for end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your form will be more complicated than a simple `ModelForm` . 
maybe you could subclass `ModelForm` and populate a new `DateTimeField` for each `DateTimeField` in the model...

as for the making of the query... it will be a work too.

think about hardcode the extra `DateField` if you want to filter for only one Model

Comment: I thought django would help a little more on this common task... Thanks